Balloon Callouts are drawn under other layer's labels
I'm having the same problem with that DMS2 wrote in Callout lines drawn under other layer's labels.
The first screenshot is "without the layer with the label using a callout”. (The layer with the label is not displayed)


In the second screenshot, the layer with the label is displayed.
The layer with the label is placed on the top of all layers, but as you can see, the labels from other layers are drawn over the callout.


The third screenshot is that I enabled the background with white color for the label.
The background is drawn over the labels from other layers, but the lines and margins of the callout are still under the labels from other layers because they are not covered by the background.


How I set is as follows:
-Using QGIS 3.34.11
-Place the layer with the labels on the top of all layers
-Set the label z-index for the layer with the labels to 5.0, and for other layers to smaller than 5.0.
-The Blend mode for the Background and for Callouts are both "Normal".
-Enable the 2mm each Margins around the label's text.
How can I get ballon callouts to be drawn over other layers, like ballon annotations?
